# Django, save a dictionary to a model with keys that may be missing

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to save a series of dictionaries to a model in Django. 
The dictionary should either create a unique entry in the model or update an existing entry if the unique id is already present. To do this I'm using the update_or_create() method.  However using the defaults to pass in the dict values, sometimes this will cause an error if a particular key is missing. 
How can deal with potentially missing keys.
e.g. entity_name_X  is not always present

Creating/Updating an entry:

```
supplier, created = Supplier.objects.update_or_create(unique_id=supplier_detail['supplierId'],
                                                        defaults={
                                                            'name': supplier_detail['supplierName'],
                                                            'entity_name_1': supplier_detail[
                                                                'supplierNameRegistered1'],
                                                            'entity_name_2': supplier_detail[
                                                                'supplierNameRegistered2'],
                                                            'rating': supplier_detail['supplierRating']})
```

Model:

```
class Supplier(models.Model):
    unique_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    entity_name_1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    entity_name_2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    rating = models.CharField(max_length=255)


def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Comment: What error you get? KeyError?

Comment: for Fields which are blank=True you can do supplier_detail.get('field_name', '') so this will set the empty value to field and it won't raise KeyError.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in views Replace:

```
supplier_detail['supplierNameRegistered1']
```

with:

```
supplier_detail.get('supplierNameRegistered1','')
```

Answer (score 2):

You are extracting values from the form using the following approach:

```
supplier_detail['fieldName']
```

This will cause  a key error if "fieldName" is not found.

Solution:

```
supplier_detail.get('fieldName','')
```